# aplicacion cliente /servidor con TCPClient

Tags: vb.net, wpf, tcp

Buenos días, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que se comunica con una caja de control y recibe datos de la mismo. la caja de control me envia una trama en ascii con la cual determino si un sensor esta siendo tapado o una bucla esta siendo pisada, y le envio una trama en ascii para controlar 2 semaforos. la comuniacion que utilizo es via serial/ethernet con un conversor. el problema que tengo es que con la clase **TCPclient**, puedo enviar datos a la caja de control sin problemas, pero cuando deseo recibir datos de la misma utilizando **tcplistener** me aparece el mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la comunicacion con la caja de control es de forma continua es decir que estoy recibiendo y enviado datos al mismo tiempo. como puedo solucionar este problema si puedo enviar por que no puedo recibir sin problemas, que estoy haciendo mal?

les adjunto un fragmento del codigo que me valida la recepcion de datos y me arroja el error.

```
Public Class RecebirDato
Public Delegate Sub ClientCarrier(conexionTcp As ConexionTCP)
Public Event OnClientConnected As ClientCarrier
Public Event OnClientDisconnected As ClientCarrier
Public Delegate Sub DataRecieved(conexionTcp As ConexionTCP, data As String)
Public Event OnDataRecieved As DataRecieved
Public Shared _tcpListener As TcpListener
Public Shadows _acceptThread As Thread
Private connectedClients As New List(Of ConexionTCP)

Public Sub New()
    AddHandler OnDataRecieved, AddressOf MensajeRecibido
    AddHandler OnClientConnected, AddressOf ConexionRecibida
    AddHandler OnClientDisconnected, AddressOf ConexionCerrada
End Sub

Private Sub MensajeRecibido(conexionTcp As ConexionTCP, datos As String)
    Dim paquete = New Paquete(datos)
    Dim valor As String
    Dim principal As New Principal
    Dim contenido As String = paquete.Contenido
    Dim valores As List(Of String) = Mapa.Deserializar(contenido)
    valor = valores(0)
    Dim msgPack = New Paquete(valor)
    conexionTcp.EnviarPaquete(msgPack)
    principal.txtObservaciones.Text = valor
End Sub

Private Sub ConexionRecibida(conexionTcp As ConexionTCP)
    SyncLock connectedClients
        If Not connectedClients.Contains(conexionTcp) Then
            connectedClients.Add(conexionTcp)
        End If
    End SyncLock
    'Invoke(New Action(Function() InlineAssignHelper(label1.Text, String.Format("Clientes: {0}", connectedClients.Count))))
End Sub

Private Sub ConexionCerrada(conexionTcp As ConexionTCP)
    SyncLock connectedClients
        If connectedClients.Contains(conexionTcp) Then
            Dim cliIndex As Integer = connectedClients.IndexOf(conexionTcp)
            connectedClients.RemoveAt(cliIndex)
        End If
    End SyncLock
    'Invoke(New Action(Function() InlineAssignHelper(label1.Text, String.Format("Clientes: {0}", connectedClients.Count))))
End Sub

Public Sub EscucharClientes(_ipAddress As String, _port As Integer)
    Try
        _tcpListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_ipAddress), _port)
        _tcpListener.Start()
        _acceptThread = New Thread(AddressOf AceptarClientes)
        _acceptThread.Start()
    Catch e As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AceptarClientes()
    Do
        Try
            Dim conexion = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim srvClient = New ConexionTCP(conexion)
            With srvClient
                .ReadThread = New Thread(AddressOf LeerDatos)
            End With
            srvClient.ReadThread.Start(srvClient)
            RaiseEvent OnClientConnected(srvClient)
        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    Loop While True
End Sub

Private Sub LeerDatos(client As Object)
    Dim cli = TryCast(client, ConexionTCP)
    Dim charBuffer = New List(Of Integer)()
    Do
        Try
            If cli Is Nothing Then
                Exit Try
            End If
            If cli.streamReader.EndOfStream Then
                Exit Try
            End If
            Dim charCode As Integer = cli.streamReader.Read()
            If charCode = -1 Then
                Exit Try
            End If
            If charCode <> 0 Then
                charBuffer.Add(charCode)
                Continue Do
            End If
            If OnDataRecievedEvent IsNot Nothing Then 
                Dim chars = New Char(charBuffer.Count - 1) {}
                For i As Integer = 0 To charBuffer.Count - 1
                    chars(i) = Convert.ToChar(charBuffer(i))
                Next i
                Dim message = New String(chars)
                RaiseEvent OnDataRecieved(cli, message)
            End If
            charBuffer.Clear()
        Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
            Exit Try
        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
            Exit Try
        End Try
    Loop While True
    RaiseEvent OnClientDisconnected(cli)
End Sub
```

End Class

de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolvi, lo único que hize fue crear una clase cliente TCP que me enviara y recibiera datos de un servidor, es clase la instancio las veces que necesite con rutas ip que se encuentren dentro del segmento de red.

gracias saludos.